# how to display unit test results from azure devops in github

Tags: github, azure-devops, jestjs, sonarqube

I have a pipeline that runs on pull requests and executes tests , it also produces an xml execution report  (it is a node project and tests run via jest) , and coverage report that I use for sonarcloud. However , the developers want to be able to see the tests results on each pr and see what tests failed in particular, so my question is whether it is possible to somehow  export and display those results in github or sonarcloud

Comment: Check out github actions: https://github.com/features/actions - you can add YAML files to automatically run your tests across various systems and for different activity (push, commit, pull, etc.)

Comment: yes, I am aware of this tool, and was thinking about using it , however I asked this question in order to get to know specifically about azure devops as I kinda wanted to use this tool as it is already used for deployment, so I thought it would be nice to use one tool for all needs, but as far as I understand ,this doesn't seem to be possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the following two methods to get the test cases metric in sonarcloud:

1. You can add **sonar.testExecutionReportPaths** in Additional Properties option in Prepare Analysis Configuration task. About [sonar.coverageReportPaths](https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/analysis/generic-test/)
   [image]
2. For SonarQube to pick up and analyse the content of the report file, you need to inform the sonar scanner. About the location of the XML file. To do so, edit the sonarqube.properties file. Please refer to [this](https://github.com/tobiashofmann/karma-sonarqube-generic-reporter).

coverage reporting:

```
 sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=reports/xxx/xxx.xml
```

In addition, you can also refer to this [similar case](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/angular-projects-unit-test-cases/9451).